# Why I do not receive the attachments in the Facebook Messenger webhook request?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Since yesterday (29/10/2020) i'm having this problem only on one of the pages linked to my app, the others work correctly:

The attached messages that the `webhook` receives from Facebook do not contain the **attachment** field.
Only messages with stickers contain the "attachment" field. All others (image, video, audio etc.) No.

What I expect (as facebook documentation) is:

```
{
  "id": "682498302938465",
  "time": 1518479195594,
  "messaging": [
    {
      "sender": {
        "id": "<PSID>"
      },
      "recipient": {
        "id": "<PAGE_ID>"
      },
      "timestamp": 1518479195308,
      "message": {
        "mid": "mid.$cAAJdkrCd2ORnva8ErFhjGm0X_Q_c",
        "attachments": [
          {
            "type": "<image|video|audio|file>",
            "payload": {
              "url": "<ATTACHMENT_URL>"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but I only receive:

```
{
    "object": "page",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "119320008135788",
            "time": 1604051633128,
            "messaging": [
                {
                    "sender": {
                        "id": "XXXXXX"
                    },
                    "recipient": {
                        "id": "XXXXXX"
                    },
                    "timestamp": 1604051632953,
                    "message": {
                        "mid": "m_7DRP...."
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**This only happens on one page from 29/10/2020**

Does anyone have the same problem / know why it happens?

Comment: I have the exact same problem.
~20% of the messages with image I receive have no attachement. Only a message id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Facebook support team` has **confirmed** my problem, and is investigating.

I am now solving using the graph api to get the desired message information using the **mid**

```
GET /v8.0/{message-id} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/message

Ex.

```
GET 

https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/' + mid + '?fields=message%2Cfrom%2Csticker%2Ctags%2Cid%2Cattachments.limit(10)%7Bid%2Cimage_data%2Cmime_type%2Cname%2Cfile_url%2Cvideo_data%7D&access_token=XXXXXX
```

Comment: any solutions about this problem? Because I'm having the same problem here...