# Facebook Graph API webhook is not sending the GIF image attachments in DMs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-webhooks

I have implemented a messenger bot application to get the Facebook DM's using Facebook Graph API webhooks and send the responses from my application. Webhook is working fine to get the messages, attachments (type: images).

**Sample webhook output:**

- Text responses:

`{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"xxx","time":123,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"yyy"},"recipient":{"id":"zzz"},"timestamp":123,"message":{"mid":"id","text":"Sample text!"}}]}]}`

- Image responses:

`{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"xxx","time":123,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"yyy"},"recipient":{"id":"zzz"},"timestamp":123,"message":{"mid":"id","attachments":[{"type":"image","payload":{"url":"<url>"}}]}]}`

**Issue**: Facebook API Webhook is **NOT** sending the attachment type ***".gif"*** images.

`{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"xxx","time":123,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"yyy"},"recipient":{"id":"zzz"},"timestamp":123,"message":{"mid":"id"}}]}]}`

Comment: FB open bug report link regarding this issue - https://developers.facebook.com/sup.../bugs/393441492018560/

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. All of my facebook pages that connect to the facebook app is stop sending an attachments. So in the meantime I use solution that purpose in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608272/why-i-do-not-receive-the-attachments-in-the-facebook-messenger-webhook-request). Hope that facebook will fix this soon.